# How can i reload only the last indexPath of collectionView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

As the title, how can i reload the last indexPath of collectionView.
I found the solution is using `collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])` method but i do not know how to code something in `at: [indexPath]`. Thank for your helping, appreciate your contribution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the index path of the last item.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: lastItem, section: lastSection)
collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
```

I leave it to you to determine the value for `lastItem` and `lastSection` since you have not provided any details. But those values should be based on the data in the data model driving your collection view.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Rmaddy. Your suggestion is enough for me. Thank you so much, appreciate your helping.